# Semi-transparent pixel support in GDI+ Graphics.DrawImage() methods

Tags: image, winapi, gdi+, imagelist

I need to draw 32-bit PNG images with semi-transparent pixels loaded into an ImageList control on a Graphics when clip rectangles may be applied to this drawing. It turned out that I can't do this with the [Graphics.DrawImage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage) method. The translucent pixels simply became gray when I tried to call some overloaded versions of `Graphics.DrawImage`.

As an example, look at the following picture:

[image]

The picture above was created with the following redefined OnPaint method of the form:

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  imageList1.Draw(e.Graphics, 10, 30, 0);

  e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[0], 10, 90);

  base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

As you can see, the first [ImageList.Draw()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist.draw) method based on the Win32 API [ImageList_DrawEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_drawex) function renders the translucent pixels correctly, while the GDI+ Graphics methods don't. I would be glad to use `ImageList.Draw` as it does the work correctly, but GDI+ clip rectangles do not work with it (because of its GDI nature).

Is there a way to draw 32-bit PNG images with semi-transparent pixels correctly with pure GDI+ methods if they can be limited by GDI+ clip rectangles?

---

If it may help, I uploaded the image into the ImageList control at design time this way:

1. Dropped the `ImageList` control onto the designer's surface.
2. Set the `ColorDepth` property to `Depth32Bit`.
3. Set the `ImageSize` property (`48, 48` for that test icon).
4. Clicked the ellipsis button in the editor of the `Images` property and added the icon in the Images Collection Editor with its Add button.

[image]

The test Mobile Phone Icon of the size 48x48 I used can be downloaded from [this source](http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pelfusion/long-shadow-media/48/Mobile-Phone-icon.png).

Comment: Show how you load the image. There is a transparent colorkey which is likely ignored in GDI+ version. You can also add sample PNG image.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I have just added what you requested to my question.

Comment: That's odd. It works fine if you use `tempImageListImages.Add(Image.FromFile("file.png"));` otherwise you get those gray edges.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, The `ImageList` class does not provide the `Add()` method. At least, in the classical WinForms and .NET. Did you mean `ImageList.Items.Add()`? In any case, I have the same gray edges if I do `ImageList.Items.Add(Image.FromFile(...))`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But it won't work if you add the image to the same imagelist, because that imagelist was initialized with the wrong size. I think that leads to the answer. Which is to initialize the imagelist with the correct size as suggested below.

Comment: My test icon is 48x48!!! I just added an explicit mention of this and the direct link to the 48x48 version of the icon to the question.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, if you decided yourself that the uploaded icon was 256x256, it's YOUR PERSONAL problem and not a reason for '-1' for my question. I see you removed all your useless comments. That's your choice that confirms one more time that your were not right... Good luck!

Comment: Wrong backcolor, it fades to black instead of white.  That happens, ImageList is GDI-based at its core and GDI is fundamentally a 24bpp rendering api.  A limitation fixed by GDI+.  You need to stop using it, ImageList is only useful as an image source for ListView and TreeView.

Comment: @HansPassant, did you mean the `TransparentColor` property of the ImageList? I tried to set it to White but this didn't help. Regarding the limitation of GDI, I see quite the contrary - GDI works correctly while GDI+ doesn't.

Comment: The fringing might be caused by failing to pre-multiply the alpha (or maybe pre-multiplying it when it wasn't needed). Transparency in general is obviously working because the image is rendered as a circle, not a square.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, give me an example of image with semi-transparent pixels that will work in my scenario (after uploading it into image list).

Comment: GDI+ can do the pre-multiplication for you, do some research.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the Graphics Property CompositingMode.

It should be set to 
`e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;`.

If not, the graphics object is not using transparency. I assume that this is done implicitly by the ImageList control if you use its draw method.

Comment: I checked `CompositingMode`. It is set to `SourceOver` by default and this does not help.